# How to use aether to get the latest timestamped snapshot dependency?

Tags: maven, timestamp, snapshot, aether

I am using aether to resolve dependencies. But in case of a snapshot dependencies where there are multiple timestamps for the same version, it does not honor the timestamps but picks the first available. How to read timestamps using aether?

I am using the following block of code to calculate both snapshot and release versions

```
public class GetDirectDependencies
   {

public static void main( String[] args )
    throws Exception
{
    System.out.println( "------------------------------------------------------------" );
    System.out.println( GetDirectDependencies.class.getSimpleName() );

    RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem();

    RepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession( system );

    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:1.0.0.v20140518" );

    ArtifactDescriptorRequest descriptorRequest = new ArtifactDescriptorRequest();
    descriptorRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
    descriptorRequest.setRepositories( Booter.newRepositories( system, session ) );

    ArtifactDescriptorResult descriptorResult = system.readArtifactDescriptor( session, descriptorRequest );

    for ( Dependency dependency : descriptorResult.getDependencies() )
    {
        System.out.println( dependency );
    }
}

}
```

This is from their documentation https://github.com/eclipse/aether-demo/blob/master/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/GetDirectDependencies.java

Comment: How does your code look like? How are you adressing the SNAPSHOT version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by configuring the following session property

```
aether.artifactResolver.snapshotNormalization=false
```

Example:

```
mvn -Daether.artifactResolver.snapshotNormalization=false  clean install
```

Comment: How did you set the config property?